# Footer appearing in main area

Tags: html

So I'm trying to create a fake website, and for some reason even though in my code I place the footer tag outside of my main tag, whenever I load the website and use the inspect tool, it says the footer tag is inside of my main tag. This is the code I typed:

```
    <main>
    <section class="one">
        <article>
            <h1>What is Hair Day?</h1>
            <p>Based in Madison, Wisconsin, Hair Day is a boutique hair salon that specializes in cut, color and styling. Hair Day also offers makeup and nail services, prides itself on its warm and relaxing atmosphere and is best known for edgy hair colors and on-trend cuts. </p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="two">
        <article>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="three">
        <article>
            <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Awesome hair styling for an affordable price!</li>
                <li>Got my hair done here, 10/10 would go here again.</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="four">
        <article>
            <h2>Our times</h2>
            <table class="times">
                <tr>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <td>12PM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div>
        <h2>Contact Info</h2>
        <p>phone: 123-456-7890</p>
        <p>email: hairdaystyles@domain.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Our Location</h2>
        <p>12345 Some Address St.</p>
        <p>Madison, Wisconsin, 98765</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And this is what shows up in the inspect element screen:
[image]

Comment: You're missing closing tags in some places.

Comment: If you see some tag not rendering where you put it, in 99% this happens because you have not correct HTML and the browser is trying to fix your mistakes. Clean up your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Please close table tags : https://prnt.sc/stgWTbqfVVBD

Example:

```html
<main>
    <section class="one">
        <article>
            <h1>What is Hair Day?</h1>
            <p>Based in Madison, Wisconsin, Hair Day is a boutique hair salon that specializes in cut, color and styling. Hair Day also offers makeup and nail services, prides itself on its warm and relaxing atmosphere and is best known for edgy hair colors and on-trend cuts. </p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="two">
        <article>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="three">
        <article>
            <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Awesome hair styling for an affordable price!</li>
                <li>Got my hair done here, 10/10 would go here again.</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="four">
        <article>
            <h2>Our times</h2>
            <table class="times">
                <tr>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <td>12PM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div>
        <h2>Contact Info</h2>
        <p>phone: 123-456-7890</p>
        <p>email: hairdaystyles@domain.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Our Location</h2>
        <p>12345 Some Address St.</p>
        <p>Madison, Wisconsin, 98765</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the close table tag

```html
<main>
  <section class="one">
    <article>
      <h1>What is Hair Day?</h1>
      <p>Based in Madison, Wisconsin, Hair Day is a boutique hair salon that specializes in cut, color and styling. Hair Day also offers makeup and nail services, prides itself on its warm and relaxing atmosphere and is best known for edgy hair colors and
        on-trend cuts. </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="two">
    <article>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="three">
    <article>
      <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Awesome hair styling for an affordable price!</li>
        <li>Got my hair done here, 10/10 would go here again.</li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="four">
    <article>
      <h2>Our times</h2>
      <table class="times">
        <tr>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <td>11AM-7PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <td>11AM-7PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <td>11AM-7PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <td>11AM-7PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <td>11AM-8PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Saturday</th>
          <td>11AM-8PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sunday</th>
          <td>12PM-8PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <div>
    <h2>Contact Info</h2>
    <p>phone: 123-456-7890</p>
    <p>email: hairdaystyles@domain.com</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Our Location</h2>
    <p>12345 Some Address St.</p>
    <p>Madison, Wisconsin, 98765</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <main>
    <section class="one">
        <article>
            <h1>What is Hair Day?</h1>
            <p>Based in Madison, Wisconsin, Hair Day is a boutique hair salon that specializes in cut, color and styling. Hair Day also offers makeup and nail services, prides itself on its warm and relaxing atmosphere and is best known for edgy hair colors and on-trend cuts. </p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="two">
        <article>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="three">
        <article>
            <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Awesome hair styling for an affordable price!</li>
                <li>Got my hair done here, 10/10 would go here again.</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="four">
        <article>
            <h2>Our times</h2>
            <table class="times">
                <tr>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <td>11AM-7PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                    <td>11AM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <td>12PM-8PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div>
        <h2>Contact Info</h2>
        <p>phone: 123-456-7890</p>
        <p>email: hairdaystyles@domain.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Our Location</h2>
        <p>12345 Some Address St.</p>`enter code here`
        <p>Madison, Wisconsin, 98765</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Good answers have an explanation in addition to code. Can you explain what you changed and why?

Comment: footer tag contains the data in the footer area, as you used the footer tag  I the middle of the HTML tags that's why the text to content shows in the middle of the page. I close the footer tag at the end so all go to the bottom of the page.